# Laravel Spatie Query Builder - create OR condition for filters

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I am using laravel spatie for filtering the model i have following filters in allowed filter array

```
$this->allowedFilters = [
        'name',
        AllowedFilter::exact('company_id'),
        'location',
        'summary',
        'client_name',
    ];
```

when I make request like

```
past-projects?filter[company_id]=${companyId}&filter[name]=${search}&filter[summary]={company_id}
```

it searches for the data which exactly contains all the passed search params with AND condition and returns no results if any of passed param do not match. I want to get results if any of the passed param match.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this issue... Here's a way I resolved it.
You could also use the callback in the query builder like this...

```
$users = QueryBuilder::for(User::class)
->allowedFilters([
'user_type',
'user_city',
AllowedFilter::exact('status')->default('new'),
AllowedFilter::callback('search', function($query, $value){
    $query->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $value . '%')
    ->orWhere('bio', 'LIKE', '%' . $value . '%')
    ->orWhere('state', 'LIKE', '%' . $value . '%')
    ->orWhere('address', 'LIKE', '%' . $value . '%');
})
])->get();
```

then the URL will look like this for example

```
?filter[user_type]=customer&filter[search]=doe&filter[user_city]=boston
```

The search parameter will be used to check the name, bio, state and address for any match.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Spatie Laravel Query Builder documentation](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-query-builder/v3/features/filtering#basic-usage) the `allowedFilters()` method will take the array of strings and return a result where all the parameters match.

**The bad news:** Therefore, it will not work as how you are intending to use it.

[image: Spatie docs #Basic Usage section]

What you want is Laravel's [Or Where Clause](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#or-where-clauses).

[image: Laravel 8 documentation Or Where Clause]

**The good news:** since Spatie Laravel Query Builder extends Laravel's default Eloquent query builder you can use both Laravel queries and Spatie queries in conjunction.

---

Say you want to get all users from "Org ABC" and from that result you want to get all users with either the name "Jack" or the location "USA" or the client_name "John" or the summary "Hello World". Then you can try

```
$result = QueryBuilder::for(Projects::class)
          ->allowedFilters(['company_id']
          ->where(function ($query) use ($name, $location, ...)
                $query
                    ->where('projects.user.name', 'like', '%$title%')
                    ->orWhere('projects.location', 'like', '%$location%')
                    ->orWhere() ....
          );

return $result
```

---

Comment: Please [do not post pictures of text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), put that text in your post (with appropriate markup).

Comment: can you explain the 'The good news' part to get my desire results

Comment: @AfzalAli i have updated the answer with the details :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score -2):

another approach; I commonly use in my projects:

https://github.com/taskinbirtan/laravel-query-builder/tree/main-so-68578125

lets say you want to OR multiple fields by choosing name OR surname fields; you can simply do it by adding 'search.name' and 'search.surname' allowed filters.
'search.' is a keyword in order to group OR fields by simply prefixing database columns with search.name, search.surname and so on.

```php
//Controller
QueryBuilder::for(UserModel::class)
  ->allowedFilters(['search.name', 'search.surname', 'type']);
```

Pseudo:

```js
// fetch {API_URL}/users?filter[search.name]=Birtan&filter[search.surname]=Taskin&filter[type]=software-engineer
(search.name==Birtan || search.surname==Taskin) && type==software-engineer
```

Comment: Code explains itself, did you read the question?